# KnockOutJS, data-bind removed the content in my dialog box

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am using knockout on one of my page. I have a list of Edit links, when you click on them, a jqueryUi dialog will show up. for some reasons, the content is removed.

```
<div id="tagDialog" data-bind="with: selectedTag">
    Tag Name:

    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name"/>

</div>
```

if I remove data-bind="with: selectedTag" from my code, the content in dialog box will show up. but I need this data-bind.

I uploaded my code on jsFiddle, you can test it there. click on "Edit" you will see.

http://jsfiddle.net/GBLNR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a minor typo.  This: `data-bind="click: $root.selecTag"` should be: `data-bind="click: $root.selectTag"`

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?